# Will Node.JS deployed on Google CloudRun utilize multiple cores?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a Node.JS app that I've deployed to Google CloudRun. When configuring CloudRun, you can choose how many cores it will use. Since Node.JS is single threaded, is there any advantage of specifying more than 1 core in the CloudRun instance? Will it ever use a second core?

If not, is the best-practice for deploying Node.JS to CloudRun to always use one core, and then let CloudRun scale number of instances based on requests count?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the answer and I am making educated and experienced assumptions. IMHO yes, multiple cores are a benefit to Cloud Run applications.

1. Requests can be overlapped, which means that multiple cores could be used if available.
2. **CPU always allocated** could take advantage of threading and multiple cores.

[How to choose the appropriate CPU allocation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#choosing)

A well-known and respected GDE wrote an article that says yes.

[Cloud Run performances with multiple CPUs](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-performances-with-multiple-cpus-a4c2fccb5192)

Comment: Hmm, I thought someone from Google cloud might be monitoring these posts...as they don't have any other direct way to ask questions. Other languages obviously will be able to use multiple cores on Cloudrun, but from my understanding, Node.js is single-threaded and on a multi-core machine, will not use more than 1 Core.  So, it seems it should only be configured with single CPU, but wanted to confirm if this is true.

Comment: @mikehennessy - My point number one indicates that all languages will benefit from multiple cores including Node.js. I recommend opening a support ticket if you want official answers from Google. Some of us are experts in our area, I am a GDE Cloud Platform. We volunteer on our personal time to answer questions like yours.

Comment: So is it ok to use pm2-runtime cluster mode as dockerfile CMD so each container will have multiple nodejs instances? Isn't it better to have multiple instances than having only one instance per container? Will this approach make cloud run open less containers if there is trafic on my service? Will it reduce costs is it just irrelevant?

Comment: @GiannisSavvidis - Create a new question

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Node.JS app that I've deployed to Google CloudRun. When configuring CloudRun, you can choose how many cores it will use. Since Node.JS is single threaded, is there any advantage of specifying more than 1 core in the CloudRun instance? Will it ever use a second core?

No, Node.js runs as a single-threaded process, and will use only 1 core by default. So specifying more than 1 core will not automatically make it utilize those cores.

BUT You can explicitly have Node.js use the [Node Cluster module](https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/02/03/improving-node-application-performance-with-clustering.html): to use several cores through spinning up multiple Node processes (that can talk to each other via some inter-process communication layer, with a little bit of  overhead and custom code).

> If not, is the best-practice for deploying Node.JS to CloudRun to always use one core, and then let CloudRun scale number of instances based on requests count?

Yes. For web services (that generally use little CPU time per request) it is the best practise.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is single-threaded but some libraries are not single-threaded for example `crypto` module.

So when you execute a function from this module, it will utilize the libuv thread pool and execute the function in parallel.

So yes, Node.js does benefit from multi CPU in Cloud Run.